# Payment method schema design

Tags: mysql

I have a few relevant tables: `user`, `payment_method`, `invoice`, `transaction`.

An **user** can own the following:

- invoices (n amount)
- payment methods (n amount)

An **invoice** own the following:

- transactions (only two, a deposit transaction and a withdrawal transaction)

The relational tables to achieve the above are `user_invoice`, `user_payment_method`, `invoice_deposit`, and `invoice_withdrawal`.

My current schema (omitting non-relevant columns) looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS invoice (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transaction (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS payment_method (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL,
    value VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL,
    dest_tag VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_invoice (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    invoice_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_user_invoice_invoice_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_user_invoice_transaction_id FOREIGN KEY (invoice_id) REFERENCES invoice (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS invoice_deposit (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    invoice_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    transaction_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_invoice_deposit_invoice_id FOREIGN KEY (invoice_id) REFERENCES invoice (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_invoice_deposit_transaction_id FOREIGN KEY (transaction_id) REFERENCES `transaction` (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS invoice_withdrawal (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    invoice_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    transaction_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_invoice_withdrawal_invoice_id FOREIGN KEY (invoice_id) REFERENCES invoice (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_invoice_withdrawal_transaction_id FOREIGN KEY (transaction_id) REFERENCES `transaction` (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_payment_method (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    payment_method_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_user_payment_method_user_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_user_payment_method_payment_method_id FOREIGN KEY (payment_method_id) REFERENCES payment_method (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

This model works for me now, however it is kind of funky. Currently I use the `payment_method` table to store all of a users payment method values. It's redundant because each user could have the same payment method name with differing values, thus creating two rows in the `payment_method` table with the same name.

I want to get rid of the duplication of payment method names. I have a fixed amount set by the system, and I want to now use the `payment_method` table to store them. When a user adds a payment method to their account, I just want a relationship to be made between a system payment method that already existed in the `payment_method` table, and a modified version of the `user_payment` table from above which will contain the values for the users payment method, while using a foreign key back to the `payment_method` table to get the name. This gets rid of my redundancy.

My proposed solution to the payment method change is this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS payment_method (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

    name VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL,

    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_payment_method (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    payment_method_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    value VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL,
    dest_tag VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL,

    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_user_payment_method_user_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_user_payment_method_payment_method_id FOREIGN KEY (payment_method_id) REFERENCES payment_method (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Was wondering if anyone has thoughts on this, or if someone has created a similar system and has a better idea. Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Here is an example structure of the invoice, containing its' two transactions, the user the created it, and the payment method selected by the user for it, as well as a few other fields:

```
type Invoice struct {
    ID                   int
    Agreement            bool
    InvoiceNumber        string
    Amount               int
    Status               string
    StatusText           string
    PaymentMethodName    string
    PaymentMethodValue   string
    PaymentMethodDestTag string
    Currency             string
    CreatedAt            time.Time
    UpdatedAt            *time.Time
    Creator              *User
    Recipient            *Recipient
    PaymentMethod        *PaymentMethod
    Deposit              *Transaction
    Withdrawal           *Transaction
}
```

Here is an example query to get an invoice with all of its' fields by invoice ID:

```
SELECT invoice.*, user.*, recipient.*, payment_method.*, deposit.*, withdrawal.*
        FROM invoice
        LEFT JOIN user_invoice
            ON user_invoice.invoice_id = invoice.id
        LEFT JOIN user
            ON user.id = user_invoice.user_id
        LEFT JOIN invoice_recipient
            ON invoice_recipient.invoice_id = invoice.id
        LEFT JOIN recipient
            ON recipient.id = invoice_recipient.recipient_id
        LEFT JOIN invoice_payment_method
            ON invoice_payment_method.invoice_id = invoice.id
        LEFT JOIN payment_method
            ON payment_method.id = invoice_payment_method.payment_method_id
        LEFT JOIN invoice_deposit
            ON invoice.id = invoice_deposit.invoice_id
        LEFT JOIN transaction AS deposit
            ON deposit.id = invoice_deposit.transaction_id
        LEFT JOIN invoice_withdrawal
            ON invoice.id = invoice_withdrawal.invoice_id
        LEFT JOIN transaction AS withdrawal
            ON withdrawal.id = invoice_withdrawal.transaction_id
        WHERE invoice.id = ?
```

Comment: I'll bet you never use `created_at` and `updated_at`.  They seem like clutter that could be jettisoned.

Comment: What is a `dest_tag`?

Comment: I have got into the habit of adding timestamps on most tables. And as for `dest_tag`, it is a payment ID/destination tag for exchanges. This is a cryptocurrency payments app.

Comment: Need to see the `SELECTs` to judge the viability of the schema, and especially the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

That's about 5 many:many relationships.  Are you sure they are all many:many, not 1:many (or many:1)?  I could envision a hundred lines in a resultset for a single invoice with multiple recipients, each paying by different methods, etc.

Maybe that's all valid, but my gut says something is wrong.

The `id` column and PK in many:many tables are in the way.  [*More tips*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).

Comment: The idea was that later on I could move from 1:m to m:m relationships (an invoice can have many recipients instead of one, for example, which is very likely to happen), and I won't have to modify the schema at all, I just modify my code.